# Can't get QtQuick AnimatedImage gif file to show in release version but works in debug

Tags: qml, qtquick2, animated-gif

I am trying to deploy an application that uses a pic.gif as an AnimatedImage.  The code works for debug but not for release.

I have the qml files and main.cpp in a folder called demo.  I have the pictures in a subfolder called images.  I have added all qml and pic files as resources but get this error when executing the release version from QtCreator:  QML AnimatedImage: Error Reading Animated Image File qrc:///images/Bear_claw.gif.

Here is qml.qrc:

```
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>demo.qml</file>
    <file>AnimatedEngine.qml</file>
    <file>images/Bear_claw.gif</file>
</qresource>
```

Here is AnimatedEngine.qml:
`
    import QtQuick 2.1

```
Rectangle {
    color: backgroundcolor
    focus: activeFocus

    AnimatedImage {
        id: sprite
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "images/Bear_claw.gif"
    }
}
```

I know this is a novice issue and I have tried many of the recommended fixes I found here and in other places like adding an alias in the .qrc file and changing the source to have qrc:///, images/images/pic.gif etc but none of the recommendations solve the problem.  I think it has more to do with an environment variable setting or something.  I am running Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you modify any of your  .qrc file you need to call *qmake*. So you have to do this almost every time you add or remove files from a project. You problably have done it for *Debug* but forgot to do this for *Release*. Simply choose *Build -> run qmake* and then try to run your project.

[image]

Comment: I tried cleaning all, running qmake, rebuilding all, but still nothing displays.  I get the same error.

Comment: @4theluvof2 So next to AnimatedEngine.qml is directory images with file Bear_claw.gif? Maybe try setting source to "qrc:/images/Bear_claw.gif". Also double check paths and names for spelling errors

Comment: I tried adding qrc:/, qrc://, and qrc:/// to the front they don't work either.  The thing is the code works when running from debug but not release... I am trying to get this thing packaged for release.

Comment: @4theluvof2 You can try to delete all Makefile files, release and debug build folders and then rebuild project (in rare cases this solves issues). Check your pro file - maybe there are specific settings only for debug or release? Also you may try to create a new project, move files here and try again. It is hard for me to guess what is the problem. Your qrc file and AnimatedEngine.qml is good for sure. The problem has to be somewhere else. - also very important - you have to run qmake after you set your build type. So first set Release and then run qmake. The other way it will not work.

Comment: I created a new project from Qt Creator using New application/QtQuickApp with Qt5.3 minimal required.  Everything else default.  The only change I make is replacing the hello world text with the AnimatedEngine.qml snippet from above.  I get the same result.  I have to be missing something somewhere.  UGH!  I see nothing in the project file specific to debug or release.  Can you suggest any other tips for why this isn't working?  Is it possible to release the debug version? Would I follow the same process to release / deploy?

Comment: @4theluvof2 Did you explicitly run qmake while Release build was selected? I have no more ideas, sorry. If you add those files to qrc, run qmake and try to run the app this has to work. If it is not working with a new project than it is very strange. Maybe try just adding .png file to the new project and load it with Image object? If you get this to work you can try with your files.